# Error when starting my rails server: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AdminUser (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I have this problem, which is when i try to start to start the rails server i get this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AdminUser (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/BackyardCoding/app/admin/admin_user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:302:in `get'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in `to'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `modules'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in `routes'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in `default_used_route'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `new'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `add_mapping'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in `block in devise_for'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/BackyardCoding/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:423:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:423:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:401:in `draw'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/BackyardCoding/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/backyardcoding/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/backyardcoding/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/backyardcoding/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/backyardcoding/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/BackyardCoding/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/BackyardCoding/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/ludvigsorensen/Desktop/backyardcoding/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I think this might be related to active_admin btw here is my gem file.....

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'toastr-rails'

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'

gem 'active_admin-sortable_tree', '~> 0.2.1'

gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.3'

gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'


gem 'mandrill-api', '1.0.52', require: 'mandrill'


gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1.0'


gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Do you know what i should do?

Comment: So i just fixed it myself. This answer helped me out: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334#issuecomment-42626409, I just had to rename my models inside the app/admin directory to plural, fx with admin_user.rb. I renamed app/admin/admin_user.rb to app/admin/admin_users.rb, and then renamed the other files to plural as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i just fixed it myself. This answer helped me out: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334#issuecomment-42626409

I just had to rename my models inside the app/admin directory to plural, fx with admin_user.rb. I renamed app/admin/admin_user.rb to app/admin/admin_users.rb, and then renamed the other files to plural as well.